# Why use the params keyword

Tags: c#, parameters, console-application

I'm brushing up on my C# skills and reading a C# book. I came across the `params` keyword in the array chapter. Why would anyone actually use the `params` keyword versus just passing a regular array to the method. I tested both approaches passing an array with and without the `params` keyword. They both worked fine. Is there any real world reason to use the `params` keyword?

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] classname = new string[5] { "cs150", "cs250", "cs270", "cs300", "cs350" };
            Prints(classname);

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void Prints(params string[] t)
        {
            foreach (var s in t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code without params:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] classname = new string[5] { "cs150", "cs250", "cs270", "cs300", "cs350" };
            Prints(classname);

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void Prints(string[] t)
        {
            foreach (var s in t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The params keyword is useful in situations where you may have a variable number of arguments passed to a method. It basically says, "Hey, whether they send 1 string or 100 strings to this method, treat them the same*" (caveats abound).  It can only be the last parameter to a method.

Comment: That's exactly what the *params* keyword does.  It's called "syntax sugar".  It is sweet.  Otherwise added to the language to keep C and C++ programmers happy, they are used to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which of these calls to `Console.WriteLine` do you find clearer?

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, you are {1}", person.Name, person.Age);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, you are {1}",
                  new object[] { person.Name, person.Age });
```

(You can't even use implicitly typed arrays (`new[]`) in the above case, unless either `person.Name` or `person.Age` is of type `object`... If they were both of type `string` you'd be okay, but it would create a string array...)

I prefer the first. It's simpler to read. That's all there is to `params` - it just allows the callers to use more concise syntax. You can still pass an array reference in the normal way, as you do in your code - but you could *also* just write:

```
Prints("cs150", "cs250", "cs270", "cs300", "cs350");
```

... which again, is simpler to read than declaring a separate variable.

Answer (score 4):

With params you can call your method like this:

```
Prints("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
```

Without params, you can’t.

Additionally, you can call the method with an array as a parameter in both cases:

```
Prints(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
```

That is, params allows you to use a shortcut when calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

With params you can call method without creating array:

```
Prints("cs150", "cs250", "cs270")
```

Comment: Well, without *explicitly* creating an array. The array is still created, it's just done implicitly.

Comment: Well, there's still the work done at execution time - that's my point. An array is still being created and populated. In very performance-sensitive code, it can be better to have several overloads to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of params keyword is

> simplify coding experience to coders whom consume the libraries or
>   methods you've cretaed.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass arguments  without "params" keyword then u can only pass the element as specified in array(array size) but with "params" you do not need to specify number of arrgument in array(array size) and can pass any number of arguments from calling function as you wish.